# getCollections is not a function from inside my Vuex Store

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, nuxt.js

I am trying to grab the documents from the sub-collections of each collection I come across for a certain user. I have a store action that first grabs the list and in the forEach loop I pass off to the second action to build the state. But when it gets to that action I get an error that getCollections is not a function.

Did something change with getCollections or is my code just wrong?

Thanks

```
      // ###########################################
      // ############# Lists #######################

      async usersLists({ commit, state }) {
        let listsData = [];
        // Check if a user is logged in.
        if (state.user) {
          await db
            .collection('lists')
            .where('list_owner', '==', state.user.uid)
            .get()
            .then(querySnapshot => {
              querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
                listsData.push({
                  id: doc.id,
                  ...doc
                });
                // Commit the state.list.id and pass off to getListAddons
                console.log('setListId: ', doc.id);
                this.commit('setListId', doc.id);
                this.dispatch('getListAddons');
              });
              commit('usersLists', listsData);
            })
            .catch(err => {
              console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            });
        } else {
          commit('usersLists', null);
        }
      },
      async getListAddons({ commit, state, dispatch }) {
        console.log('state of listid: ', state.setListId);
        await db
          .collection('link')
          .doc(state.setListId)
          .getCollections()
          .then(collections => {
            collections.forEach(collection => {
              console.log('Found subcollection with id:', collection.id);
            });
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
          });
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing has changed.  There is no getCollections() available in the Cloud Firestore client SDKs.  See how [DocumentReference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) for JavaScript clients doesn't have one listed.  It is only available in the server SDKs, for example, [in the node.js SDK](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/firestore/1.3.x/DocumentReference#getCollections).

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs `getCollections` is not supported on web client yet
, maybe you want to move this to a callable function? :)

Source: [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document)